# Signature in UIView

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

I am looking for a class that will allow the user to draw?(the main purpose is to get their signature).

I checked Cocoa Controls but couldn't find such a class. Just want to now if there's any before I start writing it myself.
Thanks

Comment: Find the Quartz Demo on the Apple developer site, should be of use.

Answer (score 4):

Look at this tutorial: http://www.ifans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=132024

To get a JPG or PNG file, you can use the functions `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` or `UIImagePNGRepresentation`. They take a `UIImage` as input. And to get a `UIImage` from a `UIView`, you can use something like this.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size);
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()]; 
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```